# Disable Divider in jQuery UI Combobox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

i have a custom autocomplete combobox, that is described here: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

jquery ui has this feature, that it automatically changes options with a label of '-' to a divider. That is neat if you want it but a pain in the ass if you dont want it.

how do i get rid of this behaviour in this example?

the documentation and some google searches provided me the solution to use the constructor methode:

```
_isDivider: function( item ) {
  return false;
}
```

https://api.jqueryui.com/menu/#method-_isDivider

but i tried to add this at the end of the autocomplete init part like so:

```
.autocomplete({ ...some parameter }).menu('instance')._isDivider = function () {
    return false;
};
```

but with no success.
I have no clue where and how to add this methode to get rid of the divider.

Has anybody any idea?

Here is the jquery ui autocomplete combobox example i copied: https://codepen.io/Killerbear_02/pen/MWgPoGW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there. You need to access ui.menu `prototype` to disable `_isDivider` method. Just paste this before `$( "#combobox" ).combobox();` in your code:

```
$.ui.menu.prototype._isDivider = function() { return false; }
```